# Prove that $\int\limits_0^{+\infty}(e^{-1/x^2} - e^{-4/x^2})\,dx$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

> How to prove that $\int\limits_0^{+\infty}(e^{-1/x^2} - e^{-4/x^2})\,dx$ converges?

I know Abel's and Dirihle's rules, but here it doesn't help. Also, i tried to use equivalence, and use only one integral.

Maybe we can say that $ e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}} - e^{\frac{-4}{x^2}} \leq $some function? How to prove integrals like this?

Comment: $$0<e^{-1/x^2}-e^{-4/x^2}\leqslant\min\{1,3/x^2\}$$

Comment: @Did How you get this?

Comment: Surely you have an idea, seeing the inequality to reach?

Comment: Think in terms of asymptotics (which is sufficient via the limit comparison test): as $x\to \infty$, $e^{-1/x^2} \sim 1 - 1/x^2$ while $e^{-4/x^2} \sim 1 - 4/x^2$, so $e^{-1/x^2} - e^{-4/x^2} \sim 3/x^2$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler If $f(x)\sim g(x)$ and $u(x) \sim v(x),$ it does not follow that $f(x)-u(x)\sim g(x)-v(x).$

Comment: @zhw. OK, so I was actually technically using asymptotic series: so $e^{-1/x^2} \sim 1 - 1/x^2$ is shorthand for: $e^{-1/x^2} \sim 1$ and $e^{-1/x^2} - 1 \sim -1/x^2$.

Comment: @danielschepler Why not simply use big O and little o notations?  It will clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **It is straightforward to show that the integral converges (the integrand is $\displaystyle O(x^{-2})$ as $x \displaystyle \to \infty$).  In fact, we can evaluate this integral in closed form.  To this latter end we proceed.**

---

Enforcing the substitution $x\to 1/x$ reveals

$$\int_0^L \left(e^{-1/x^2}-e^{-4/x^2}\right)\,dx=\int_{1/L}^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2}-e^{-4x^2}}{x^2}\,dx \tag 1$$

Integrating by parts the integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ with $u=e^{-x^2}-e^{-4x^2}$ and $v=-\frac{1}{x}$ yields

$$\int_0^L \left(e^{-1/x^2}-e^{-4/x^2}\right)\,dx=\left.\left(\frac{e^{-x^2}-e^{-4x^2}}{x}\right)\right|_{1/L}^\infty-2\int_{1/L}^\infty \left(e^{-x^2}-4e^{-4x^2}\right)\,dx\tag 2$$

Letting $L\to \infty$ we find that the first term on the right-hand side of $(2)$ vanishes and we obtain

$$\int_0^L \left(e^{-1/x^2}-e^{-4/x^2}\right)\,dx=-2\int_{0}^\infty \left(e^{-x^2}-4e^{-4x^2}\right)\,dx=\sqrt \pi$$

> Therefore, the integral not only converges, but is equal to $\sqrt \pi$.